# How do I change a variable inside a module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I’m stuck on writing this module pattern for a tic tac toe game. When I click on a tile, it doesn’t increment  `gameBoard.tileCounter`

```
const gameBoard = (() => {
    const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board > div')
    let tileCounter = 0;
    
    tiles.forEach(tile => tile.addEventListener('click', () => {
        tileCounter++;
    }))
    
    return {tileCounter};
})();
```

If I do  `gameBoard.tileCounter++` it works, but shouldn’t I just be able to do  `tileCounter++`

Comment: The whole point of the Module pattern is that it doesn't create lots of global variables. The only global variable is `gameBoard`, everything else is properties of that object.

Comment: @BrentHarris Where did he say anything about React?

Comment: It's also not possible to create a global variable that's an alias for an object property. If you assign `let tileCounter = gameBoard.tileCounter` updating one of them won't affect the other.

Comment: check out [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). `return { get tileCounter(){ return tileCounter; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a module pattern is to access to the properties of that module instead of having a lot variables dangling, so in your scenario you can return a function to get the counter.

Something like this might work:

```
const gameBoard = (() => {
  const tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".game-board > div");
  let tileCounter = 0;

  tiles.forEach((tile) =>
    tile.addEventListener("click", () => {
      tileCounter++;
    })
  );

  const getTileCount = () => tileCounter

  return { getTileCount };
})();
```

And by doing `gameBoard.getTileCount()` you will be able to get the actual count

Comment: Alternatively, `return { get tileCount() { return tileCounter; } };`

Comment: Oh ok this makes sense, thank you! So does that mean I should avoid returning variables in module patterns?

Comment: You should return only the elements you need to interact with, in your scenario by returning the `tileCount` you were returning a copy of the variable instead of the actual reference of the variable, by returning the function or `getter` you can access to the scope of `tileCount` as needed - hope it makes sense

Comment: Oh I see yea that makes sense, thanks! There was another thing I was confused about that I didn’t include in my original post. 

When I create an array inside ```gameBoard```, for example ```let board = []``` and edit the array while inside  ```gameBoard```. 

And if I ```return { board }``` I am able to console.log(gameBoard.board) and see the updated array. So why can I do that with arrays but not variables?

Comment: In that case the array might be mutating, I will recommend to read this article to learn a bit more about mutations https://vtechguys.medium.com/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating-8606d9b78c77

Comment: Interesting, thanks again for your help!